# Adding an ovirt Node. Which version to choose?

Tags: ovirt

I have an existing ovirt 4.1 cluster to which I would like to add a new node. Do I need to install the exact Node version the other nodes are running on? Or is it ok to use the latest minor version for the node?

Comment: It's a good idea to have all the nodes at the latest version

Comment: My question was about adding a new node to a cluster with a specific lesser minor version.

Comment: The answer is update everything to the latest and add a node that is also latest

Answer (score 1):

You can safely install a newer version like **oVirt Node 4.2** as far as you keep your current Cluster compatibility version. I have personally tested it in production, it works perfectly.

Unfortunately, there's no community documentation on this but you can peek at the [Red Hat Virtualization Life Cycle](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/rhev) where you can find a compatibility matrix under paragraph **Red Hat Hypervisor Upgrade and Support Policy**.

To this day, oVirt Node 4.2 is backward compatible with Cluster level 4.1, 4.0 and 3.6.